# MS-DOS standard output interrupt and function

Tags: assembly, dos

I need to write a resident program which grabs console output to the file. To do this I have to know what interrupt and function DOS uses to print its output to console, to rewrite this interrupt. But I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It would all be `int 21h`.

Comment: Thanks(wasn't sure about 21h), what about function? Which one does it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last step DOS uses the TELETYPE OUTPUT for to print its output to console:
RBIL->inter61a.zip->INTERRUP.A

```
--------V-100E-------------------------------
INT 10 - VIDEO - TELETYPE OUTPUT
AH = 0Eh
AL = character to write
BH = page number
BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
Return: nothing
Desc:   display a character on the screen, advancing the cursor and scrolling
  the screen as necessary
Notes:  characters 07h (BEL), 08h (BS), 0Ah (LF), and 0Dh (CR) are interpreted
  and do the expected things
IBM PC ROMs dated 1981/4/24 and 1981/10/19 require that BH be the same
  as the current active page
BUG:    if the write causes the screen to scroll, BP is destroyed by BIOSes
  for which AH=06h destroys BP
SeeAlso: AH=02h,AH=06h,AH=0Ah
```

And here is an other way for to set and get an interrupt vector:
RBIL->inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.F

```
--------D-2125-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 1+ - SET INTERRUPT VECTOR
AH = 25h
AL = interrupt number
DS:DX -> new interrupt handler
Notes:  this function is preferred over direct modification of the interrupt
  vector table
some DOS extenders place an API on this function, as it is not
  directly meaningful in protected mode
under DR DOS 5.0-6.0, this function does not use any of the
  DOS-internal stacks and may thus be called at any time; however,
  under Novell DOS 7.0 - DR-DOS 7.02, this function was not reentrant.
  Since 1998/05/29, DR-DOS 7.03 no longer uses any internal stacks and
  tests for this function much earlier, to allow a minimal stack usage
  of just two words in addition to the IRET frame, allowing it to be
  called from INT 21h functions, specificially device drivers.  This
  fixes the MCS SMB client
Novell NetWare (except the new DOS Requester) monitors the offset of
  any INT 24 set, and if equal to the value at startup, substitutes
  its own handler to allow handling of network errors; this introduces
  the potential bug that any program whose INT 24 handler offset
  happens to be the same as COMMAND.COM's will not have its INT 24
  handler installed
SeeAlso: AX=2501h,AH=35h

--------D-2135-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 2+ - GET INTERRUPT VECTOR
AH = 35h
AL = interrupt number
Return: ES:BX -> current interrupt handler
Note:   under DR DOS 5.0+, this function does not use any of the DOS-internal
  stacks and may thus be called at any time
SeeAlso: AH=25h,AX=2503h
```

A little variation of the end of our ISR:

```
myisr:
....etc....

           DB 0EAh ; jmp far
old_dosint DW ?, ?
```

Edit:
RBIL->inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.F

```
--------D-2109-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 1+ - WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
AH = 09h
DS:DX -> '$'-terminated string
Return: AL = 24h (the '$' terminating the string, despite official docs which
    state that nothing is returned) (at least DOS 2.1-7.0 and
    NWDOS)
Notes:  ^C/^Break are checked, and INT 23 is called if either pressed
standard output is always the screen under DOS 1.x, but may be
  redirected under DOS 2+
under the FlashTek X-32 DOS extender, the pointer is in DS:EDX
SeeAlso: AH=02h,AH=06h"OUTPUT"
```

Example:

```
STRING DB "Hello","$"

mov ah,9
lea dx,STRING
int 21h
```

Comment: Wow, that takes me back! Yes, I couldn't remember who called whom but int 10h is the bios screen output so that's who does the writes. The BIOS was always slow so direct screen writes were the way to go for speedy box draw "graphics"... If you wanted to change stderr to stdout then int21h/09 would be the one but capturing console then int10h is better. The question title does say "MSDOS standard output...".

Comment: I use direct screen writes most times. But only the "MSDOS standard output" can be redirect to a printer, or file.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference for this type of question used to be Ralf Brown's interrupt list.

This is INT21h, [subfunction 09h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) "Write string to standard output".

Redirecting (chaining in this case) interrupts isn't simple. Prepare for crashes.

Edit in sympathy. To chain properly, you read the vector for int21h from 0:xxxx and store it (2 words, segment:offset)

```
old_dosint  dd   ?

    mov      ax, 0
    mov      es, ax
    les      bx, es:[21h * 4]    
    mov      word ptr [old_dosint], bx   
    mov      word ptr [old_dosint + 2], es
```

Then save your own ISR, call it myisr, into the vector (disable ints first):

```
    cli
    mov      ax, 0
    mov      es, ax
    mov      es:[21h * 4], offset myisr
    mov      es:[(21h * 4) + 2], cs
    sti
```

Your isr will chain:

```
myisr:
    cmp      ah, 09h
    jne      myisrexit
    ....etc....

myisrexit:
    jmp      dword ptr cs:[old_dosint]
```

Comment: it is not 09h, because when DOS prints something, it doesn't use my code (i'm printing my string instead of what should be printed). I need to know how SYSTEM prints it's messages to console. It is definetely not 09h.

Comment: And instead of rewriting interruption vector one can save old interruption with dos 35h, and then load new one with dos 25h function.